# Obtain path to program associated with a file

Tags: java, windows, file, registrykey

Given a file, I want to come up with a programatic way in Java to get the path to the exe that this file is associated with(this is Windows). I'm doing this because I want to launch another application from my own. I also need to know when the file is closed so I can update data in my app.

Currently it works by using a process but I have hardcoded the path to the exe so it seems like this is the missing piece. I'm almost certain I should be looking at the registry for that info but under Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT{fileExt} I can only see a folder named ShellEx and in it, two strange values such as {2EC1BE78-0401-44B1-87EF-1A5966D5C5D0}. Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, this can be retrieved using the commandline commands `ftype` and `assoc`, as you can see in following example:

```
Prompt>assoc .docx
.docx=Word.Document.12

Prompt>ftype Word.Document.12
Word.Document.12="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
```

So the issue comes down on how to launch commandline commands and reading their results, in Java. There should be plenty of posts about this (a simple Google led me to [this URL](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Execute_an_external_program_and_capture_the_output)).

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Desktop.open() to open the file in the associated native application, for example the file you want to open is c:\somefile.png, to open it in the associated application is easy as

```
 Desktop desk = Desktop.getDesktop();
 desk.open(new File("c:/somefile.png"));
```

As to the other part you can use Java Watch service API to determine if the file changed while it was open.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice

https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-8-watchservice-api-tutorial/

As an alternative there is also the File Monitor in the Apache Commons IO
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

A small comparison of the two can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-watchservice-vs-apache-commons-io-monitor-library

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would probably work but it would require some refactoring of the existing code as it is making the thread wait for a process to finish and I was hoping to avoid making too many changes.